# How to remove selected array values in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's consider an array & it's values are

```
int[] array = {0, 0, 1, -1, -1,-1, 1, 1, 1};
```

I want to remove first three values of the array...?

& my result should be `array = {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1}`

Thanks in advance....!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't remove items from an array - it has a fixed size.

However, you could create a *new* array with only the values you want. With LINQ that's easy:

```
int[] newArray = array.Skip(3).ToArray();
```

If you want to modify an *existing* collection to add or remove values, you want [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead and its [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) method:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {0, 0, 1, -1, -1,-1, 1, 1, 1};
list.RemoveRange(0, 3);
```

Comment: It did the trick, this is what I was looking for.. Thanks a lot JON,

Answer (score 4):

You can't resize an array, so you need to create a new one.
You could use `array.Skip(3).ToArray()` for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple linq function to skip the first records.

```
int[] array = { 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1 };
int[] array2 = array.Skip(3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Linq handy you can do:

```
array = array.Skip(3).ToArray<int>();
```

Comment: Does not compile, since Skip returns an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

> this is a solution from list approach to your problem.. i know this is
>   little bit long but i think for people who getting started with C#
>   generics must know this kinda stuff too..

**add a button to your win-form then double click it and paste this code the hit F5 or run button**

```
        // define array or use your existing array
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        // lets check the number of elements in array first
        MessageBox.Show("Array has " + array.Length.ToString() + " elements only");
        // creating list
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        // assigning array to list
        myList = array.ToList();

        // removing first 2 values from list
        // first argument is the index where first item should remove 
        // second argument is how many items should remove
        myList.RemoveRange(0, 3);

        // testing our list
        MessageBox.Show("List count is: "+ myList.Count.ToString());
        string firstItem = myList[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("First Item if the list is :"+firstItem)

        // now if you want you can convert MyList in to array again
        array = myList.ToArray();

        // if you debug and see you will see now the number of elements in array is 7
        MessageBox.Show("New Array has " + array.Length.ToString() + " elements only");

                     ***Best Regards and Happy Programming***
```